# How to make emacs perform the same as other editors on tab character?

Tags: emacs, emacs23

The TAB key in emacs is bound to indent-for-tab-command, but the indent itself converts all the tabs into spaces, which I didn't like because it's harder to locate character in the code and the code gets bigger.

I tried to use (setq-default indent-tabs-mode t), (setq tab-width 4) or (setq default-tab-width 4), none of the above works. Neither the width of \t character changes, nor the indent uses tabs instead of spaces.
And 'M-x tabify' does not work either.

I searched for a long time but got nearly nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: actaully there're different situation in different mode, I mainly tested on cc-mode and java-mode. Got it work already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your .emacs settings, if you don't have any special settings in your .emacs file, tab should be inserted by default.

```
;; This will force emacs to insert spaces instead of tabs
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)
```

This other two settings are not related.

Check emacswiki.org for any Emacs related questions.

Comment: Seems working now. But a strange thing is that when pressing backspace on the tab, the tab will be converted into spaces. But when using arrows to move or <C-d>, the tab is treated as tab as normal. Why is this?

Comment: Check what's your backspace key is mapped with Ctrl-h K "Backspace". It should be "backward-delete-char", if it's something with "tabify" fix it in your .emacs like this "(gloabl-set-key [backspace] ‘backward-delete-char)"

Comment: That's exactly it. And in cc-mode, it's c-electric-backspace which uses backward-delete-char-untabify by default. Finally got it work. Thanks a lot!